# Load dictionary to a template in Django

Tags: django, templates

At the moment, I'm generating menu by adding to CONTEXT_PROCESSOR

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
'blog.context_processors.menu_processor',
 )
```

function returning dictionary

```
from blog.models import Category, Page

def menu_processor(request):
    return {
        'category_list': Category.objects.all(),
        'page_list': Page.objects.all(),
    }
```

so I can iterate it at any template.

But for portability reason I want to make it another way. What is the way to just {% load categories_list %} every time it's needed? I've been trying by custom tags and filters, but without success.

Comment: A custom tag is the way. You'll need to be more specific about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Could you just pass it in as a list, using `render_to_response` from your view, whenever you need it?

Comment: @trpt4him he would have to do that for every view that loads the menu (possibly each view there is) which is not very DRY. Daniel is correct, this needs a custom tag.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, good point, thanks.

Comment: Could you guys tell me what kind of tag would it be?
I predict it's gonna be inclusion tag, but dunno how to pass dictionary in that.